# Varien_Http_Client: getQuery() returns nothing

Tags: api, varien, http-request

I'm trying to use Varien_Http_Client for calling external API, here's the code:

```
    $httpClient = new Varien_Http_Client();
    $httpClient->setUri('https://api-host/api/endpoint');
    $httpClient->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::GET)
    $httpClient->setParameterGet([
        'name' => 'John',
        'gender' => 'male',
    ]);

    $params = $httpClient->getUri()->getQuery();
```

The problem is `$httpClient->getUri()->getQuery()` returns nothing if I set the GET parameters using `setParameterGet()` like above, shouldn't it suppose to return `name=John&gender=male`?

**Updated: getQuery() after calling request, getting same result**

```
    $httpClient = new Varien_Http_Client();
    $httpClient->setUri('https://api-host/api/endpoint');
    $httpClient->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::GET)
    $httpClient->setParameterGet([
        'name' => 'John',
        'gender' => 'male',
    ]);

    try {
        $response = $httpClient->request();
        Mage::log($httpClient->getUri()->getQuery());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($e);
        return $e;
    }
```

One more thing, it works if I set the parameters this way

```
$httpClient->setUri('https://api-host/api/endpoint?name=John&gender=male');
```

Answer (score 2):

because you have not sent the request yet, you should:

```
$httpClient = new Varien_Http_Client();
$httpClient->setUri('https://api-host/api/endpoint');
$httpClient->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::GET)
$httpClient->setParameterGet([
    'name' => 'John',
    'gender' => 'male',
]);
$httpClient->request();
$param = $httpClient->getUri()->getQuery();
```

Before `$httpClient->request()` is called, the Uri's query is null

Comment: Yes I have tried that and getting same empty result, please see my updated question.

Comment: have you tried the another URI ? Seems the https://api-host/api/endpoint cannot access. I have tested with google.com and it's worked.